# Apply UDF on an Array of StructType

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with the following schema :

```
root
 |-- urlA: string (nullable = true)
 |-- urlB: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- distCol: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to use a UDF to access the element in the structure so that I can sort the distCol values and get the url (in urlB) where the distCol is the smallest (top N actually)

Input:

```
+--------------------+---------------------------------+
|                urlA|                             urlB|
+--------------------+---------------------------------+
|            some_url|[[0.02, url_0], [0.03, url_1],...|
+--------------------+---------------------------------+
```

Output (ideally):

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|                urlA|                                urlB|
+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|            some_url|[[url_best_score_0, url_best_0],...]|
+--------------------+------------------------------------+
```

My udf:

```
def rank_url(row_url):
    ranked_url = sorted(row_url[0], key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)[0:5]
    return row_url

url_udf = udf(rank_url, ArrayType(StringType())

df = model.approxSimilarityJoin(pca_df, pca_df, 1.0).groupBy("datasetA.url").agg(collect_list(struct("distCol", "datasetB.url")).alias("urlB")).withColumn("urlB", url_udf("urlB"))
```

I want to do something like that but row_url is not really accessible that way. Do you have any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue comes from your UDF output type and how you access your column elements. Here's how to solve it, `struct1` is crucial.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, DoubleType, StringType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Define structures
struct1 = StructType([StructField("distCol", DoubleType(), True), StructField("url", StringType(), True)])
struct2 = StructType([StructField("urlA", StringType(), True), StructField("urlB", ArrayType(struct1), True)])

# Create DataFrame
df = spark.createDataFrame([
        ['url_a1', [[0.03, 'url1'], [0.02, 'url2'], [0.01, 'url3']]],
        ['url_a2', [[0.05, 'url4'], [0.03, 'url5']]]
    ], struct2)
```

Input :

```
+------+------------------------------------------+
|urlA  |urlB                                      |
+------+------------------------------------------+
|url_a1|[[0.03, url1], [0.02, url2], [0.01, url3]]|
|url_a2|[[0.05, url4], [0.03, url5]]              |
+------+------------------------------------------+
```

UDF :

```
# Define udf
top_N = 5
def rank_url(array):
    ranked_url = sorted(array, key=lambda x: x['distCol'])[0:top_N]
    return ranked_url
url_udf = F.udf(rank_url, ArrayType(struct1))

# Apply udf
df2 = df.select('urlA', url_udf('urlB'))
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
+------+------------------------------------------+
|urlA  |rank_url(urlB)                            |
+------+------------------------------------------+
|url_a1|[[0.01, url3], [0.02, url2], [0.03, url1]]|
|url_a2|[[0.03, url5], [0.05, url4]]              |
+------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast and the trick with struct1 is precisely what I needed. Thank you Arius!

Comment: [@Arius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7193352/arius) while defining structure I am getting `NameError: name 's1' is not defined`

Comment: @PIG my bad, I renamed my variables without enough precaution. `s1` referenced to `struct1`. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Arius could you please explain, use of `[0:5]` in sort

Comment: @PIG He wanted to keep only the top N urls, where N = 5. I'm editing to make it clearer.