# Spark UDF for Array[Struct] as input

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, user-defined-functions

I have a DataFrame with the following schema :

```
   |-- user_loans_arr: array (nullable = true)
         |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
           |-- loan_date: string (nullable = true)
           |-- loan_amount: string (nullable = true)
```

so I want to create udf function which takes user_loans_arr as input and return some string after some processing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply UDF on an Array of StructType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55956028/apply-udf-on-an-array-of-structtype)

Comment: you need a function which takes an argument of type `Seq[Row]`. Inside the UDF you can extract stuff from `Row`